# Cli Batch Mode don't support module add command

Tags: command-line-interface, wildfly, wildfly-13

I'm executing some commands using cli batch mode on Widlfly 13, but the command **module add** doesn't respect the "all-or-nothin" pattern. Because it executes before I finish the batch proccess, executing the command **run-batch**. Someone knows what's the reason?  There are other commands with the same behavior?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, because the CLI mode batch works with operations that allow for low level interaction with the management model, generally knowed like  Operation requests. The module add command is a hight level operation. The formal specification for operation request is:

[/node-type=node-name (/node-type=node-name)*] : operation-name [( [parameter-name=parameter-value (,parameter-name=parameter-value)*] )]

Example:
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=postgres:add(driver-name="postgres", driver-module-name="org.postgresql", driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver)